# Pressing CTRL+SHIFT+J takes me back to "previous" question

Tags: bug

Just noticed this today:

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in order to open the browser console takes me back to *previous* question (and opens the console, too).

To reproduce the error:

- Go to stackoverflow.com home page
- Choose any question except the first one; **note the question above it**
- Click the question
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on the question page
- Notice that you land on the question I asked you to look at

I am using Chrome version 43.0.2357.65 dev-m

**Update:**

Not confirmed, but possibly related to [new navigation for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing) feature.

Comment: No repro on Firefox, the console opens just as it should and it does not go back to the previous question for me.

Comment: can't repro at my side.

Comment: Oh, It's related to the buttons, yes I had them at some point but not anymore.

Comment: Ohh yes got it. first i open question in new link so. Yes that thing happen in firefox also.